# How to get at an XML attribute and value in ColdFusion 8?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8.

I am trying to get at the BoothID attribute and value of the ExhibitorList.  Here's my XML:

```
<ExhibitorList BoothID="164991">
    <BoothNumber>N1849</BoothNumber>
    <CompanyID>407</CompanyID>
    <CompanyNumber>166212</CompanyNumber>
</ExhibitorList>
```

I am successfully able to get to anything I want except for the

```
SoapResponse = xmlParse(httpResponse.fileContent);
ResponseNodes = xmlSearch(SoapResponse, "//*[ local-name() = 'ExhibitorList' ]");
for (i = 1; i lte arrayLen(ResponseNodes); i++) {
    BoothNumber = ResponseNodes[i].BoothNumber;
    CompanyID = ResponseNodes[i].CompanyID;
    CompanyNumber= ResponseNodes[i].CompanyNumber;

    BoothID = xmlSearch(ResponseNodes[i], "@BoothID");  // THE TROUBLE IS HERE

}
```

How do I need to rephrase this to get at the BoothID attribute and value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your line that ends in // THE TROUBLE IS HERE with

```
BoothID = ResponseNodes[i].XmlAttributes.BoothID;
```

Comment: Shawn, you are too good to me.  That worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI and as an adjunct to Shawn's god answer: the online docs are useful in answering this sort of question.  There's a fairly big section on XML handling: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/XML_01.html; the most helpful page in answering your question is this one: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/XML_17.html.

Comment: @AdamCameron, thanks for the links. I work very little with XML. I wouldn't know the right answer until I implemented it.  I find Adobe documentation especially lacking.  I certainly did try them though.

Comment: Yeah, Evik you're dead right: the CF docs can be a bit rubbish @ times, and these XML docs are a good example of this.  It's very odd that one needs to dig down quite so far in those XML docs before one sees an example of what one needs to do to pull an attribute out, and even then it's not like a "here's how to do it", it's just a "by the by" sort of thing.  That said, if you've checked the docs as part of your research before posting, it's handy to mention that, too.